# Build and Debug application outside the default package

Tags: flash-builder

If I try to build an application with the application class outside the default package, so the application file path is /app/AppClass.mxml instead of /AppClass.mxml (as would normally be the case), Flash builder cannot launch the application for debugging because it is looking for the SWF in debug/app/AppClass.swf and the SWF is being output to debug/AppClass.swf instead.  Changing the output folder to debug/app makes it put the swf in debug/app, but then it puts the application configuration file "AppClass-app.xml" in /debug/app/app and then that can't be found.

Is there a way to change *only* the SWF output folder, or the location of the xml configuration file in the run-configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use symbolic link to created swf file - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

for example for Windows :

> cd project/path/bin-debug/package/path/
>   MKLINK ClassName.swf project/path/bin-debug/ClassName.swf

and it's work

or you can use symbolic link for folder:

> cd project/path/bin-debug/package/
>   MKLINK path project/path/bin-debug/ /D

Answer (score 0):

I think I remember [this](http://pastebin.com/1knCRSjM) worked for me. But it was long time ago. And, yes, it is a known problem, I also recall Adobe people mentioning it as a limitation of FB.

In my Ant script, you'll need to do the adjustments to reflect your actual file names and directory structure. Also note that it will make it more cumbersome to debug it from FB. You'll need to use the debugging target in Ant, and then connect the debugger to the running application (so that some info, especially on the startup) will be lost. The only way you would be able to debug it, though I've never tried it, is with the commandline tools (I'm not sure of adl syntax for breakpoints / printing / stack frames, so idk how to do it.

Also, for the released application you will probably want to change the signing mechanism.